# Redmine 500 Error after migrating data to new instance 3.2 -> 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to migrate my data from an older instance of redmine (3.2) to a new one (4.0).

My new redmine server runs ubuntu 20.04 and is configured as follows

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.0.6.stable
  Ruby version                   2.7.0-p0 (2019-12-25) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  5.2.3
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
SCM:
  Git                            2.25.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

I followed https://computingforgeeks.com/install-redmine-on-ubuntu-linux/ to create it.

Once I moved the database over, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` to perform any necessary migrations, which appeared to execute successfully, although it did report a few warnings (https://pastebin.com/yzNpHiKm) - I'm not sure if they're relevant as I don't know much about ruby.

I can see all of my old tickets are there etc, but when I try to view one or create a new one it throws a 500, reporting the following into the logs

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 205ms (ActiveRecord: 21.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `accessor' for #<ActiveModel::Type::Value:0x00005625fa76b6c0>):
    15: <% end %>
    16:
    17: <% if @issue.safe_attribute? 'assigned_to_id' %>
    18: <p><%= f.select :assigned_to_id, principals_options_for_select(@issue.assignable_users, @issue.assigned_to), :include_blank => true, :required => @issue.required_attribute?('assigned_to_id') %></p>
    19: <% end %>
    20:
    21: <% if @issue.safe_attribute?('category_id') && @issue.project.issue_categories.any? %>

app/models/role.rb:223:in `permissions_all_trackers'
app/models/role.rb:232:in `permissions_all_trackers?'
app/models/role.rb:238:in `permissions_tracker?'
app/models/project.rb:554:in `block in assignable_users'
app/models/project.rb:554:in `assignable_users'
app/models/issue.rb:934:in `assignable_users'
app/views/issues/_attributes.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_issues__attributes_html_erb___775154800353400985_73440'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1249:in `labelled_fields_for'
app/views/issues/_attributes.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_issues__attributes_html_erb___775154800353400985_73440'
app/views/issues/_form.html.erb:44:in `block in _app_views_issues__form_html_erb___962050841117096496_73420'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1249:in `labelled_fields_for'
app/views/issues/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_issues__form_html_erb___962050841117096496_73420'
app/views/issues/_edit.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_issues__edit_html_erb___2491441640301013004_73400'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1242:in `labelled_form_for'
app/views/issues/_edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_issues__edit_html_erb___2491441640301013004_73400'
app/views/issues/_action_menu_edit.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_issues__action_menu_edit_html_erb__2036666379799696235_73380'
app/views/issues/show.html.erb:139:in `_app_views_issues_show_html_erb___1022264146824026390_73240'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in show'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:100:in `show'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

As mentioned I'm no ruby/rails expert, but from what I can understand this doesn't seem specifically to be a problem with redmine - rather with my ruby/rails configuration.

When I re-run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following warnings

```
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1855: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1368: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:12: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95: warning: The called method `select_all' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:260: warning: The called method `transaction' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:171: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:97: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:705: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:105: warning: The called method `_update_record' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:13: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/schema_statements.rb:44: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:11: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/56823 and also this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16971

Comment: Yeah I've seen both of those. The first appears to be exactly my issue but gives no solution and the second appears to be the same error in quite a different context and no solid solution (that I can understand with my extremely limited ruby knowledge)

Comment: You shouldn't use this mix of `Ruby` and `Redmine` versions. See [official compatibility list](https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Ruby-interpreter)

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: I did yes - as per @LyzardKyng comment - it was an incompatible mix of Ruby and Redmine versions